# Oracle sequence nextval issue on Derby

Tags: java, sql, oracle, derby, mybatis

We are having multiple MyBatis queries in our application above an Oracle database, which use sequences to generate their own ID values for further usage

```
<insert id=...>
    <selectKey keyColumn="some_id" keyProperty="someId" order="BEFORE" resultType="int">
        select s_seq1.nextval from dual
    </selectKey>
    insert into some_table 
    (some_id, some_data, created_on, created_by) 
    values
    (#{someId}, #{someData}, #{createdOn}, #{createdBy})
</insert>
```

We are now trying to write integration tests for the application using Derby database, but since that has no dual table, we tried to make the above queries work by creating a fake view called dual, which contains the sequence nextval expressions as its columns. Liquibase changeset with two example columns is as follows

```
<changeSet id="create_dual_view">
    <sql><![CDATA[create view dual as select 1 "s_seq1.nextval", 2 "s_seq2.nextval" from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;]]></sql>
</changeSet>
```

Checking the Derby content, this view is succesfully created, however while running the test we still receive exception for the above query

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'S_SEQ1.NEXTVAL' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification 
and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list.
```

The problem seems to be that due to the dot we had to create the fake view columns between quotes, so the MyBatis query would also work on Derby with the column name between quotes, but this then would make the real application on Oracle fail. This seems to be a deadlock situation. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution can be to execute a different query based on the underlying database. See http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html ("Multi-db vendor support" section) and http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#databaseIdProvider.

The code should look like this:

```
<insert id=...>

    <selectKey keyColumn="some_id" keyProperty="someId" order="BEFORE" resultType="int">

        <if test="_databaseId == 'oracle'">
          select s_seq1.nextval from dual
        </if>
        <if test="_databaseId == 'derby'">
          [...]
        </if>

    </selectKey>

    insert into some_table 
    (some_id, some_data, created_on, created_by) 
    values
    (#{someId}, #{someData}, #{createdOn}, #{createdBy})

</insert>
```

Comment: Good idea, thank you. Our eventual solution was actually to switch to H2 due to multiple issues with Derby.